# How to avoid slow loading of Jquery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm new to PHP and Jquery. There is a division which uses Jquery to display the images in a lightbox. But, I don't know why the images are loading slowly.
Below is the code :

```
<div class="image-zoom" rel="lightbox" id="gallery">
        <div id="album1" style="margin-right:18px;" rel="lightbox">
            <?php
            if (isset($albums[0])) {
                $i = 1;
                foreach ($albums[0]['photos'] as $photo) {
                    if ($i == 1) {
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?= $photo ?>" rel="lightbox">
                            <img src="<?= $photo ?>" width="214" height="160" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="zoom-magnifier" id="gallery">
                            <a href="<?= $photo ?>" rel="lightbox">
                                <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/images/zoom-icon.png" id="zoom"/>
                            </a>
                            <div id="more-text" align="left" ><?=$albums[0]['title']?></div>
                        </div>
                        <?php

                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?= $photo ?>" rel="lightbox"></a>
                        <?php
                    }
                    $i++;
                }              
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="album2" rel="lightbox">
            <?php
            foreach (array(1, 0) as $album_id) {
                if (isset($albums[$album_id])) {
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach ($albums[$album_id]['photos'] as $photo) {
                        if ($i == 1) {
                            ?>
                            <a href="<?= $photo ?>" rel="lightbox">
                                <img src="<?= $photo ?>" width="214" height="160" />
                            </a>
                            <div class="zoom-magnifier">
                                <a href="<?= $photo ?>" rel="lightbox">
                                    <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/images/zoom-icon.png" id="zoom1"/>
                                </a>
                                <div id="more-text2" class="more-txt-link"><?=$albums[$album_id]['title']?></div>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        } else {
                            ?>
                            <a href="<?= $photo ?>" rel="lightbox"></a>
                            <?php
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }                        
                    break;
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

Below is the lightbox script :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#album1 a').lightBox();
        $('#album2 a').lightBox();
    });
</script>
```

So when the page is loaded for the first time nothing comes in the division.But `when I refresh` the page I get it correct.Why is it happening like this. Why does it appear only when refreshed again and not for the first time.How can I avoid this

Comment: Anyone please guide me on this

Answer (score 0):

1. `when the page is loaded for the first time nothing comes in the division.But when I refresh the page I get it correct.` -- In first time maybe your photos are not  fully downloaded.
2. To improve speed, dont use orginal pictures from  `<img src="<?= $photo ?>" width="214" height="160" />`. Use  214x160px thumbs for thumbs ;)
3. Try  put javascript in footer to improve page loaded time. If your jquery is set on ready, then its starts when page open, and maybe all page content not yet downloaded.

**UPDATE**

If you use Yii, You wrealy whant use MVC not signle file.

Comment: `Try put javascript in footer to improve page loaded time.`- What do you mean by this. where should I put this script

Comment: No it is same, nothing changed

Comment: I think, good practise is put all javascript code in footer before </html> tag. Did you change orginal picture to thumb size?

Comment: In code I have already resised it to 214*600. Whre shuld I change then...pls guide me

Comment: Not in code, but you don`t need original picture like 2000px1400px (2mb) to show litle width="214" height="160" thumb. (10-60kb) I think this is general problem

Comment: Open Firefox FireBug  and on NET tab select all. Then Reload Page. There will be timings. What section is the longest? Peste all results

Answer (score 0):

I expect the images you are loading are much bigger than 214x160 - the browser is downloading the full image (which may be a big file) and then squeezing it into the defined size of the `img` tag.

To get around this, resize the images to 214x160 in an image editor or use a dynamic resizer such as [TimThumb](https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/) or [ImageResize](http://codecanyon.net/item/imageresize/59935) (by me!), which sits on your server and resizes the images as requested.

Comment: I already resized the images in the <img> tag.But still it does not work.Can you suggest me something else